# Менеджемент enum, или чистка кода

Tags: c#, c++, c, enum

Поделитесь опытом, кто что использует для чистки `enum`? Со временем, обычно накапливается много значений, часть из которых уже отсутствуют в коде. Особенно это относиться к `enum`'у ошибок проекта. Чистить руками сразу вызывает сонное состояние и апатию :)

Есть конечно grep и xarg, но возможно есть уже готовый инструмент? Или технология. Хотелось бы автоматизации процесса.

Comment: Для С# и для C/C++ способы скорее всего будут разные. Лучше уж сделать два отдельных вопроса...

Comment: Для С/С++ можно попробовать написать 'простенькую' утилиту поверх libclang.

Comment: почему, не соглашусь, в клиент-серверных решениях пишется как правило один `enum` для `c++` и `c#` - с дефайнами только.

Comment: Решарпер. 6 символов нужно

Comment: Может я неправильно понял вопрос, но обычно в IDE есть функция типа "safe delete" для удаления неиспользуемых сущностей. Если значений много и вы хотите удалить все сразу, то опять же можно воспользоваться "clean code" из меню рефакторинга вашей IDE. Всё это никак не связано с ЯП или `enum`

Comment: `но обычно в IDE есть функция типа "safe delete"` вот не встречал, надо внимательно посмотреть, если не сложно, приведите пример IDE с этим функционалом.